# parameter expansion default ":=" vs "=" vs ":-" vs "-"

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

I've seen several different methods of using default values in parameter expansions in Bourne-derived shells: `:=`, `=`, `:-` and `-`. I'm wondering how they differ. The manual says that `-` and `=` handle null values differently from `:-` and `:=`. But as far as I can tell, `:=` == `:-` and `=` == `-`. Is this true?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: The manual describes the behavior of each, but as far as I can tell, :- and := behave exactly the same. I'd like to confirm whether that is really the case.

Comment: They do not; the equal forms actually change the value of the parameter is the default is used.

Comment: The difference is that `:=` assigns the default value to the variable in addition to returning it.

Comment: Add `echo $my_var` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: This is also covered in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A demonstration of `:=` vs `:-`:

```
 $ unset foo
 $ echo ${foo:-bar}
 bar
 $ echo foo
 
 $ echo ${foo:=bye}
 bye
 $ echo $foo
 bye
```

`:-` only affects the result of the expansion, leaving the parameter unchanged. `:=` actually assigns the default value *to* the parameter if it is null or unset.

`=` works analogously to `-` regarding unset parameters; it only changes the value of `foo` if it is unset, not if it has a null value.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is explicit.

With the `=` forms, emphasis added:

> If *parameter* is unset or null, **the expansion of word is assigned to *parameter*.**  The value of parameter is then substituted. [...]

With the other forms:

> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

No **assignment**, modifying the parameter's value when later expanded as a variable, takes place without using an `=` form.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question has already been answered, I just want to post a link to the [shell bible](https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible#expansion), where you can find a great explanation not only to the parameter expansion, but to almost everything shell related.